# Select a default constructor from a list of subclasses using a string

Tags: c#, oop

I have a simple system that creates a certain subclass based on a string input from the user. Currently it looks like this:

```
Command command;

switch (commandName)
{
    case "move":
        command = new MoveCommand();
        break;
    case "turn":
        command = new TurnCommand();
        break;
    case "jump":
        command = new JumpCommand();
        break;
}
```

Is there a way to make this a bit more generic? So instead of having a switch statement like this that contains 30 different cases, is there a way to embed the data (in this case the string name of the command) in the definition of the subclass itself? So something like:

```
var subclass = allSubclassTypes.FirstOrDefault(s => s.CommandName == commandName); 
var command = subclass.InvokeDefaultConstructor();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can System.Reflection to dynamically invoke the constructor. Something like below would work but would require some validation for the explicit cast.

```
public static Command GetCmd(string cmdName)
{
    Command cmd;
    
    var cmdType = Type.GetType(cmdName);
    var ctor = cmdType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    
    return (Command)ctor.Invoke(parameters: null);
}
```

Here's an example if you want to test it out
https://dotnetfiddle.net/MQnefH

Comment: Thanks! However this just invokes the default constructor. In my example cmdName isn't the name of the class itself but needs to be part of some definition of the class such that it can be selected. Is there any mechanism for that? Thanks!

Comment: of course it can, as long as there is a field that you can discern as a programmer. reflection will be able to tell at runtime